not able to launch jupyter notebook from anaconda
When I launch Jupyter Notebook from Anaconda, a web page opens and gives me the below error message

Your file couldn’t be accessed
It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I have just installed Anaconda and want to practice Python on Jupyter Notebook. I am connected to Anaconda cloud also. I have logged into Anaconda Navigator and clicked on Launch for Jupyter Notebook. The version Anaconda Navigator is 2.5.2 and that of Jupyter Notebook is 7.2.2. The error message is

Your file couldn’t be accessed
It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

The url that is displayed is "file:///C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-17212-open.html"



I had the same problem, my solution is to right click the Anaconda Prompt, run as amdin
Type in "jupyter notebook", enter
Find something similar to this:
To access the server, open this file in a browser:

    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8892/tree?token=76208b8310b636f74891efcad4f001d463b47a850a05a2e4
        http://127.0.0.1:8892/tree?token=76208b8310b636f74891efcad4f001d463b47a850a05a2e4


double click the address will highlight the whole, then Ctrl+C ONE TIME, Ctrl V to the browser, it works for me.
remember to Ctrl+C just ONE TIME, twice will stop this server and shut down all kernels

I faced the same issue as you did. I went to the exact location where the file was supposed to be, and it was indeed there. I clicked to open it in the browser and was able to access it again through Anaconda. This approach worked for me! 

I'll check and get back to you. Thanks for sharing

I also faced the same problem two hours ago.I solved it by unsetting read-only option in general tab of folder properties of runtimes in "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\jupyter".
After that I relaunch jupyter from anaconda and it allowed me to run.
